# update table from another table in db2 9

Tags: db2

hi i run this script "
UPDATE      t1
  SET  T1.col1= T2.col1
FROM   aaa   t1   ,
bbb   t2
WHERE 
T1.col2=138802
AND T1.col3 >=8800084 and  T1.col3 <=8852884
AND T1.col4=0
AND T1.col5=T2.col2"
 and i get syntax error !!! (ILLEGAL USE OF KEYWORD FROM)
how i can run this script???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a modified version:

```
UPDATE aaa t1
  SET T1.col1 = (SELECT T2.col1 FROM bbb t2 WHERE T1.col5=T2.col2)
  WHERE T1.col2=138802 AND T1.col3 >=8800084 and T1.col3 <=8852884 AND T1.col4=0
```

I isolated the T2 stuff in a subquery with an explicit SELECT. Note that the subquery will run for every row that is updated.