# How do I write an SQL statement (for DB2) to update a table with these conditions?

Tags: sql, db2

Here's what I need to do:

For each row in Table1 where Name is not null or blank, and Table2 has a row with matching Name, replace another column in Table1 with the contents of a column from Table2, and set the name in Table 1 to null.

I can't seem to wrap my head around getting that logic into SQL.

I don't really care if Table2 has multiple rows with matching Names, just grabbing the first one is good enough.

Comment: Consider [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708082/update-table-from-another-table-in-db2-9) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14312885/update-table-with-value-from-another-table)

Comment: I mustaccio a question... I was able to use the syntax in that first link to successfully update the column, but now when I try to set the Name to null whenever the other column is not null, I get "APPLICATION RAISED ERROR WITH DIAGNOSTIC TEXT: INVALID BRANCH ID". Google doesn't know what it means.

Comment: It's your application custom exception. Apparently your _other column_, which is probably called `BRANCH_ID` or something like that, cannot be null. It's often useful to actually read error messages before pasting them into Google.

Comment: It's not called branch id, the word branch doesn't appear anywhere in the database, and that column can be null.

Comment: Then check your application code (might be a trigger, for example) to see what it thinks is a valid branch ID.

Comment: Yeah it's an update trigger, I'm checking with a DBA.

Answer (score 0):

In `DB2` you could use the `MERGE` statement to do the job

```
MERGE INTO Table1 A
USING Table2 B
     on A.name=B.name  
WHEN MATCHED
   THEN UPDATE SET A.another_column=B.Table2_Column
    , A.name=NULL;
```

In T-Sql
You would use an `UPDATE` statement with a join criteria that would only impact the **matching rows**, something like the below:

```
Update A
set A.another_column=B.Table2_Column
, A.name=NULL
From Table1 A
inner join Table2 B
on A.name=B.name
Where isnull(A.name,'')<>''
```

Comment: This SQL statement is not valid in DB2.

Comment: What's wrong with it? Looks like `ifnull` replaces `isnull` -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65071/isnull-function-in-db2-sql

Comment: I get an error at "Table2" -- ILLEGAL SYMBOL "Table2". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE: (. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.63.75 SQL Code: -104, SQL State: 42601

Comment: The question is tagged DB2. Why did you include a T-SQL answer?